# Batch file to check if files exist in a directory that don't exist in a filelist

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that recurses my folders against a file list and basically creates two reports. One if a file exists and one if a file does not exist.
What I'd like to do now is find out if a file exists in the directories but does not exist in the filelist (i.e do I have extra files).

Here's my current file..

```
FOR /F "usebackqdelims=" %%f IN ("filelist.txt") DO (IF EXIST "%%f" (ECHO %%f exists >> "%~dp0\Exists.txt" ) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> "%~dp0\doesntexist.txt" ))
```

Comment: You might be interested in the `findstr` command: `findstr /X /L /C:"file_name" "filelist.txt"` returns an `ErrorLevel` of `0` in case `file_name` has been found within `filelist.txt` and `1` otherwise; type `findstr /?` in a command prompt window for help...

Answer (score 1):

The standard Windows console application **FINDSTR** is for this task definitely a very good choice as it can be seen by the code below.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ListFiles=%~dp0FileList.txt"
set "ListExist=%~dp0Exist.txt"
set "ListMissing=%~dp0NotExist.txt"
set "ListExtra=%~dp0Extra.txt"
set "ListCurrent=%TEMP%\ListCurrent.tmp"

rem Get list of all files in current directory and its subdirectories with
rem full path into a temporary list file. If the current directory tree
rem contains no file, delete empty list file and exit batch processing.
dir /A-D /B /ON /S >"%ListCurrent%" 2>nul

if errorlevel 1 (
    copy "%ListFiles%" "%ListMissing%" >nul
    if exist "%ListExist%" del "%ListExist%"
    if exist "%ListExtra%" del "%ListExtra%"
    goto EndBatch
)

%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X    /G:"%ListFiles%" "%ListCurrent%" >"%ListExist%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X /V /G:"%ListExist%" "%ListFiles%"   >"%ListMissing%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X /V /G:"%ListExist%" "%ListCurrent%" >"%ListExtra%"

:EndBatch
del "%ListCurrent%"
endlocal
```

This batch code requires that `FileList.txt` in directory of the batch file contains the file names with full path.

**Note:** `%~dp0` expands to path of batch file ending already with a backslash. Therefore don't specify an extra backslash before file name.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?` ... most important to understand how filtering the lists work.
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>`, `>nul` and `2>nul`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Load the list of filenames in *the subscripts* of an array
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%f IN ("filelist.txt") DO set "name["%%f"]=1"

rem Process files, remove elements of existent files from array
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   IF defined name["%%f"] (
      ECHO %%f exists >> "%~dp0Exists.txt"
      set "name["%%f"]="
   ) ELSE (
      ECHO %%f is extra >> "%~dp0ExtraFiles.txt"
   )
)

rem Report remaining elements in the array
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%f in ('set name[') do (
   ECHO %%~f doesn't exist >> "%~dp0doesntexist.txt"
)
```

Comment: Thanks guys - this one almost works. The issue now is that the 'Extra files'  output only shows files i the same directory as the batch file; it doesn't seem to be searching through the directory structure where my files are although the Exists/Doesn't Exist reports are. IN 'Filelist'txt' i have the path to each file but only from where it is in relation to the batch file (i.e on the full path just folder1\folder2\file.txt

Comment: Well, you didn't showed us the contents of `filelist.txt` file, so we can only guess... The `for` command just process the files in current directory, so you need to add `/R` switch to it this way: `for /R %%f in (*.*) do (`. Note that the names in the text file must have _the same format_ of the names returned by `for /R`; just run the `for /R` from the command-prompt with an `@echo %f` command to see this format.

Comment: Sorry, my filelist is heavily NDA'd!

Comment: The /R works a treat. Now my problem is that is recurses the entire folder's subdirectories as opposed to the ones laid out in the filelist. For example, let's say I have a subdirectories 'Red' and 'Gold'. I only want to search through files in 'Red' and have that path name in my file list. The /R also makes it go through the 'Gold' directory. I'm guessing I now need to set Red and Gold as variables..?